# Allocating a list of pointers in CUDA

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda, double-pointer

So, I'm trying to allocate a list of pointers, each pointing to a struct on my device, but I keep getting a segfault. This works fine on with a normal `malloc`, but with `cudaMalloc`, things get fishy.

```
struct body //struct holding information for one body
    {
        int id;
        float m;                    //mass
        float a[3];             //acceleration
        float v[3];             //velocity
        float pos[3];            //x, y, z
    } ;

body** devBodies;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&devBodies, n * sizeof(body*) );

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cudaMalloc( (void**)&devBodies[i], sizeof(body));
    }
```

I want each pointer in the list to point to my structure.
Why is this not working?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't working because `devBodies[i]` is stored in device memory and isn't directly writeable by the host. So the inner `cudaMalloc` calls are failing.

The solution is to assemble the contents of `devBodies` in *host* memory and then copy that to the device. Your code snippet becomes something like:

```
struct body //struct holding information for one body
    {
        int id;
        float m;                //mass
        float a[3];             //acceleration
        float v[3];             //velocity
        float pos[3];           //x, y, z
    } ;

body** devBodies;
body** _devBodies = new body*[n]; // shadow copy of devBodies

cudaMalloc( (void**)&devBodies, n * sizeof(body*) );

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&_devBodies[i], sizeof(body));
}

cudaMemcpy(devBodies, _devBodies, n * sizeof(body*));
```

Note that you then need to use the contents of `_devBodies` to pass to host side APIs.

As a general rule, this type of array of pointers is a very poor fit for GPU computing. The setup code on the host is unnecessarily complicated, and the performance on the device is inferior to flat memory because of all the additional pointer indirection required to access data.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you are trying to achieve, it seems like you're creating a number of structs ( more specifically, `n` structs ).

Is there a reason why you can't do the following?

```
struct body //struct holding information for one body
    {
        int id;
        float m;                    //mass
        float a[3];             //acceleration
        float v[3];             //velocity
        float pos[3];            //x, y, z
    } ;

body* devBodies;
cudaMalloc( (void*)&devBodies, n * sizeof(body) );
```